# WLST: deploying shared library not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, weblogic, wlst

I'm trying to deploy `jax-rs` shared library using WLST. Here is the implementation:

```
deploy(name, path, targets, 'true')
```

And here is the log

```
Starting an edit session ...
Started edit session, be sure to save and activate your changes once you are done.
Deploying application from /u01/oracle/user_projects/domains/KkvA4/../../../wlserver/common/deployable-libraries/jax-rs-2.0.war to targets KkvA4Cluster (upload=false) ...
You have an edit session in progress, hence WLST will not block for your deployment to complete.
Started the Deployment of Application. Please refer to the returned WLSTProgress object or variable LAST to track the status.
Saving all your changes ...
Saved all your changes successfully.
Activating all your changes, this may take a while ... 
The edit lock associated with this edit session is released once the activation is completed.
Activation completed
Successfully disconnected from Node Manager.
```

However, the library is deployed as web application installation, not as shared library. Why?

Answer (score 1):

When using the deploy() function you have to set option libraryModule to true to force the module to be deployed as a shared lib.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use libraryModule='true' for the 4th parameter:

```
deploy(name, path, targets, libraryModule='true')
```